# Dynamically create class instances from given strings and save deep copy in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create multiple class instances (copied) dynamically from a set of given strings and got stuck with it.

Here's my approach:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


# I have an number of different classes
class FourLegs:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age


class TwoOrNoLegs:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

# And only the class name and some attributes (normally in a big CSV file)
dc = dict(zip(range(0, 5), [('FourLegs', 'Dog', 11),
                            ('TwoOrNoLegs', 'Chicken', 22),
                            ('FourLegs', 'Cat', 33),
                            ('FourLegs', 'Mice', 44),
                            ('TwoOrNoLegs', 'Snake', 55)]))


# And want to create different objects depending on the given class name
# and attributes an store them in a dict
zoo = {}
for k, v in dc.items():
    an = eval(v[0])
    an.name = v[1]
    an.age = v[2]
    print(an, an.name, an.age)
    zoo[an.name] = an

for k, v in zoo.items():
    print(k, v.name, v.age)
```

which delivers:

```
<class '__main__.FourLegs'> Dog 11
<class '__main__.TwoOrNoLegs'> Chicken 22
<class '__main__.FourLegs'> Cat 33
<class '__main__.FourLegs'> Mice 44
<class '__main__.TwoOrNoLegs'> Snake 55
Snake Snake 55
Mice Mice 44
Dog Mice 44
Cat Mice 44
Chicken Snake 55
```

because I am using (eval()) which seems to create only references (and no copies) of the instances.

The result I would like to produce (and which works if I create instances manually) is the following:

```
<class '__main__.FourLegs'> Dog 11
<class '__main__.TwoOrNoLegs'> Chicken 22
<class '__main__.FourLegs'> Cat 33
<class '__main__.FourLegs'> Mice 44
<class '__main__.TwoOrNoLegs'> Snake 55
Snake Snake 55
Mice Mice 44
Dog Dog 11
Cat Cat 33
Chicken Chicken 22
```

I got really stuck here and am glad for every hint!

Is there a way to achieve this also for dynamically created instances based on strings?

Comment: Note that your sample `dc` dictionary creates integer keys; you may just as well just use a list in that case. You are ignoring the key in your `dc.items()` loop as well, a straightforward `for v in dclist:` would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not creating *instances*, you are setting attributes directly on the class instead. Because you are altering attributes on the *same two classes* each time, you see the last values set reflected in the attributes on these two classes.

*Call* your class, passing in the name and age:

```
for k, v in dc.items():
    an = eval(v[0])(v[1], v[2])
    print(an, an.name, an.age)
    zoo[an.name] = an
```

You should really try to avoid using `eval()` here; put your classes in a dictionary and use that as the lookup, or use the `globals()` dictionary (but beware that that enables other globals to be called too):

```
classes = {'FourLegs': FourLegs, 'TwoOrNoLegs': TwoOrNoLegs}

for k, v in dc.items():
    clsname, name, age = v
    an = classes[clsname](name, age)
    print(an, an.name, an.age)
    zoo[an.name] = an
```

Comment: I forgot something in my question. Is there also a way to set attributes of the created instances subsequently, e.g. an = eval(v[0]) and then an.name = 'My pet', an.age=99? I'll adapt my answer later..

Comment: @CordKaldemeyer: you'd have to adjust your class definitions; currently passing in a name and age is *required*.

Comment: I mean just setting the values for name and age subsequently not the creation of additional attributes.

Comment: @CordKaldemeyer: yes, and you still need to create your instance first. You can't currently create an instance without passing in values for name and age. If you *remove* those requirements from the `__init__` method (or just remove the method altogether) you can create instances of the classes without passing in value and thus can set them independently later.